# How would I "decode" the packet data from a pcap in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, pcap

I'm wanting to make a PCap Analyzer script where it can detect what traffic is what from a pcap file.

The general idea is: `HTTP(x10), DNS(x5), HTTPS(x20)`

Now as you can see the majority of traffic is HTTPS based I want to be able to pull that from the pcap packet data to pass to another section of my analyzer script.

I don't have a clue nor any idea of what NPMs or anything that I can use, I have looked into `pcap-parser` which is a 9+ Yr old NPM *[this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pcap-parser)* , and only provides `packet.data`, `packet.header`.

I'm just completely losing all hope on making this script as I've tried ever potential resource even went into researching a potential API system to upload the pcap and bring the info I wish to obtain with no avail.

Example of `packet.header`

```yaml
{
  timestampSeconds: 1606145597,
  timestampMicroseconds: 444357,
  capturedLength: 60,
  originalLength: 60
}
```

Example of `packet.data` (Buffer)

```yaml
<Buffer 01 00 5e 7f ff fa 34 29 8f 99 09 70 08 00 45 00 00 a5 a4 76 00 00 04 11 10 f3 0a c8 06 1d ef ff ff fa ed 0c 07 6c 00 91 17 56 4d 2d 53 45 41 52 43 48 ... 129 more bytes>
<Buffer ff ff ff ff ff ff 34 29 8f 99 09 6e 08 06 00 01 08 00 06 04 00 01 34 29 8f 99 09 6e 0a c8 06 e6 00 00 00 00 00 00 0a c8 06 de 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ... 10 more bytes>
<Buffer e0 55 3d 5e 95 a0 40 ec 99 d3 06 fd 08 00 45 00 05 6b a7 ed 40 00 80 06 00 00 0a 91 a6 ce 34 ef cf 64 e9 9f 01 bb a2 30 72 ed d9 06 6d cc 80 18 02 00 ... 1351 more bytes>
<Buffer 40 ec 99 d3 06 fd e0 55 3d 5e 95 a0 08 00 45 00 00 34 72 2d 40 00 70 06 e2 e3 34 ef cf 64 0a 91 a6 ce 01 bb e9 9f d9 06 6d cc a2 30 14 19 80 10 1b 25 ... 16 more bytes>
<Buffer e0 55 3d 5e 95 a0 40 ec 99 d3 06 fd 08 00 45 00 00 34 05 b4 40 00 80 06 00 00 0a 91 a6 ce 17 d9 8a 6c e9 a8 01 bb f0 0d cc ed 00 00 00 00 80 02 fa f0 ... 16 more bytes>
```

Comment: Why not use tshark and then capture its output with node?

Comment: I'm using Node to Exec command lines to dump and convert pcaps to .txt files in tshark but I wish to get the following: HTTPS, HTTP, DNS, SSH, TELNET (etc) Protocols @RossJacobs

Comment: Have you ever taken a look at node_pcap package? I used this in my project to analyze cyber attacks and I successfully analyzed PCAP files up to 55GB.

Comment: @jvda by chance do you have a repo of this project I can look at to study, and No I haven't really looked into that package, but now you have mentioned it I shall do.

Comment: Sure @Johnty. We use it in the `miner` subfolder of [this visualization system](https://github.com/ddosgrid/ddosgrid-v2) to extract information. You can run that directly on the shell to get statistics. Since you said you're writing an analyzer script, you might want to implement your own miner subclass (miner/miners) which hides a lot of the complexity. We are still doing active research with this project - if you have any question feel free to contact jvda AT vonderassen.com.